# What is a working Regex Expression for MM/DD/YYYY?

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I have searched the web and found plenty of expressions for this format but yet none have worked. I used multiple test sites and all failed :( So i'm hoping i can solve this by asking for help! I simply need the regular expression for validation on a date in the format range of
01/01/20XX  to 12/31/20XX

also passes this

1/1/20XX to 12/31/20XX

Once i get this expression, i'll be validating a constant string also which i'll append onto the end which will be 12:00:00 AM. Hope this mystery of such a common format gets solved soon! :)

Comment: are you going to validate it on `client side` or on `server side`...This makes a lot of difference...

Comment: I am hoping to validate client side, seems clunky to me to validate on a postback and then have to update the values and postback again. client side validation is much smoother imo.

Answer (score 10):

You don't want a regex for this. Really. You want to use [DateTime.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) or [DateTime.TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) (unless this is for javascript, in which case you really should have included that as a tag).

Comment: I am using a asp regularexpressionvalidator but the parse might be a possibility if i cannot get the regex for it.

Comment: @user1732364 Ah... Yeah, why MS did not include a DateTimeValidator control is beyond me. The good news is that it's easy to inherit your own from CustomValidator that will use `DateTime.TryParse()` on the server the javascript Date object's `parse()` method on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$
```

if you need further explanation about the single digits see here: [regex description](http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexbuddy/datemmddyyyy.html)

**UPDATE:**

If you wanna check for date and time use this regular expression:

```
^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d ([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm|AM|PM)$
```

I tested this one with the value "02.02.2012 12:00 AM" ... it works for me.

Comment: This expression works great for the date part!!!! My next question is how can i get it to work with 12:00:00 AM attached to the end? I have some jquery that appends that onto the end of the date making it look like this in the textbox: 01/01/2000 12:00:00 AM

Comment: My expression i have right now is                                             "^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d\s12:00:00\sAM$"